# Unable to track location using the Ahoy gem Rails 5.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ahoy

I just installed the ahoy gem into my Rails 5.1.3 application. I am getting back the `visit` and the `event`, but the visit location attributes always return `country: "Reserved"`, `region: nil`, `city: nil`, `postal_code: nil`. This is what I have implemented following the directions on the Ahoy github. Any body can shed some light on what it is I am missing or doing incorrectly? This is occurring in both production and development env's.

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ahoy.trackAll();
});
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'ahoy_matey'
```

**Example of a Visit:**

```
[2] pry(main)> Visit.last
  Visit Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "visits".* FROM "visits" ORDER BY "visits"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Visit:0x007fd045e04b48
 id: 2,
 visit_token: "7750594c-7163-46c1-8ec7-18f3069619d0",
 visitor_token: "efdcb332-742a-4de3-971b-c141f24ff0f6",
 ip: "74.174.236.84",
 user_agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
 referrer: nil,
 landing_page: "http://my_website.com/users/sign_in",
 user_id: nil,
 referring_domain: nil,
 search_keyword: nil,
 browser: "Chrome",
 os: "Mac OS X",
 device_type: "Desktop",
 screen_height: 800,
 screen_width: 1280,
 country: "Reserved",
 region: nil,
 city: nil,
 postal_code: nil,
 latitude: 0.0,
 longitude: 0.0,
 utm_source: nil,
 utm_medium: nil,
 utm_term: nil,
 utm_content: nil,
 utm_campaign: nil,
 started_at: Wed, 22 Nov 2017 21:10:52 UTC +00:00>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. One of my apps which has geocoder installed directly as a gem is allowing me to get back the location params without any trouble on every visit, although that is a rails 4.2.6 application. My rails 5.1.3 app, which is configured the exact same way, is the one with the issues exactly to yours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the `Ahoy` gem itself as it just tracks user devices, not the location services. To get location attributes we can use `Geocoder` along with Ahoy.

**Gemfile**

Add `Geocoder` into your Gemfile as it is listed as a dependency in the Ahoy [documentation](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#geocoding):

```rb
gem 'ahoy_matey'
gem 'geocoder'
```

## Geocoding

It can be achieved via one of the below approaches:

##### 1. As Background Job (Default and Recommended)

Geocoding is performed in a background job so it doesn’t slow down web requests. The default job queue is `:ahoy`. Enable Geocoding and background job queue in config/initializers/ahoy.rb:

```rb
Ahoy.geocode = true

Ahoy.job_queue = :default # Ahoy suggests `:low_priority`
```

Start background job processing library, if you are using `sidekiq` type in terminal:

```bash
$ sidekiq
```

##### 2. Without Background Job (Not Recommended)

No need to enable geocoding and setting job queue in config/initializers/ahoy.rb, simply add this code in the `Ahoy::Visit` model to set attributes yourself.

```rb
after_validation :update_geolocation_data

private

def update_geolocation_data
  location = Geocoder.search(ip).first

  return if location.blank?

  self.city = location.city
  self.region = location.region
  self.country = location.country
  self.latitude = location.latitude
  self.longitude = location.longitude
end
```

## Development

IP address behaves differently in the development and production environments. If you debug the IP address in the development/test environment from the Ahoy object or simply with `request.ip` it will look like `127.0.0.1` or `::1` which is not a valid IP to detect a location.

Add this code to your config/environments/development.rb:

```rb
class ActionController::Request
  def remote_ip
    # Write any IP address you'd like here.
    "71.212.123.5"
  end
end
```

**Restart the server** and an updated IP address and location data will be added to the Ahoy object:

```rb
> Ahoy::Visit.last
  Ahoy::Visit Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "ahoy_visits".* FROM "ahoy_visits" ORDER BY "ahoy_visits"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Ahoy::Visit:0x00007fc6a84fa698
 id: 18,
 visit_token: "28ff1d9d-f680-4bfc-8fa9-0235c73a24ff",
 visitor_token: "c7ad1fac-e05f-4008-b2a9-4ac60893d638",
 user_id: 3,
 ip: "71.212.123.5",
 user_agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
 referrer: "http://localhost:3000/dashboard",
 referring_domain: "localhost",
 landing_page: "http://localhost:3000/dashboard",
 browser: "Chrome",
 os: "Mac",
 device_type: "Desktop",
 country: "US",
 region: "Washington",
 city: "Seattle",
 latitude: 47.5412,
 longitude: -122.275,
 utm_source: nil,
 utm_medium: nil,
 utm_term: nil,
 utm_content: nil,
 utm_campaign: nil,
 app_version: nil,
 os_version: nil,
 platform: nil
 started_at: Fri, 06 Oct 2023 11:37:49.004724000 UTC +00:00>
```

##### Ways to get a Random IP address:

1. Using random method:

   ```rb
   Array.new(4){rand(256)}.join('.')
   ```
2. Using [Faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/main/doc/default/internet.md) gem in development/test:

   ```rb
   Faker::Internet.ip_v4_address
   ```

## Production

After adding Geocoder Gem and configuring it with Ahoy as mentioned above, it will work fine.